# Create an SQL inserting script from Django to populate a PostgreSQL database

Tags: python, sql, django, postgresql, django-views

I'm currently trying to insert in a Django model some complex data extracted from multiple parsed files. Because I have a huge amount of data to insert I don't want to multiply the queries to the database from my Django script.

Is there a way to generate an SQL script instead of executing all the `object_to_insert.save()` and inserting the script by using `psql -f my_script.sql` ?

Answer (score 2):

If it's only one table, there is a bulk_create method in the Django ORM queryset: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/querysets/#bulk-create

This method takes a list of objects and insert them on the database by an an efficient way, generally in only one query if the database supports multiple inserts.

Comment: It's a very interesting possibility but I have multiple interconnected tables so it's not the most optimized solution I can imagine.

Comment: You know the primary key of all objects being inserted?

Comment: I define some primary keys but there is some tables with linked objects that use the django default serial field as primary key. I think it could be a problem to create an insertion script.